# PThread monitoring

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

How does one get the status of a Pthread and what would be a good way to monitor the threads statuses continuously so that if anything goes wrong I can kill the other threads that are linked?

I have two threads, one depends on the constant calculation result and I want to monitor the threads and kill a thread which might end up running alone.

What is a good way of doing this?